# JWT Token From AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-cognito

Is there another better way to get the JWT token vs. from the URL of the callback when using AWS Cognito?

I see several examples where folks have the callback include the token in the URL, but that does not seem like it is preferable vs getting it from the page header.

Suggestions and here is a video I am referring to - https://youtu.be/oFSU6rhFETk?t=1513

Comment: Yes, google 'authorization code flow Cognito'

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary- Could you perhaps add a link to what you see as a better approach please.